# How to divide a number of students into different groups in a way that contains approximately the same number of boys and girls

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I'm working on a school programming project, and I need to assign each student a group, so that all groups have approximately the same number of boys as girls.

In addition the old students keep the same group, so I initially have 2 groups (A and B) with some students already assigned and a list to assign the group. Each group has a maximum number of students allowed.

For example:

-Numbers of students previously assigned:

```
          Group A                     Group B
       --------------             ---------------
        Boys      6                 Boys     12
        Girls     9                 Girls     8
       --------------             ---------------
        Total     15                Total     20
```

-Numbers of students to assign:

```
       --------------             ---------------
        Boys      8                 Girls     4
       --------------             ---------------
```

-Maximum number of students per group:

```
       ------------------------------------------
                  25 students per group
       ------------------------------------------
```

-Solution to be obtained:

```
          Group A                     Group B
       --------------             ---------------
        Boys      13                 Boys     13
        Girls     11                 Girls    10
       --------------             ---------------
        Total     24                Total     23
```

-The process I followed to reach this solution is as follows:

```
1. I have calculated the total number of boys and girls:

  Total Boys: 6 + 12 + 8 = 26
  Total Girls: 9  + 8 + 4 = 21

2. I have calculated half of both amounts:

  Total Boys:   26 / 2 = 13
  Total Girls:  21 / 2 = 10 (10.5)

3. I have calculated the difference between the students assigned and the 
   students remaining to be assigned until the amount obtained previously:

          Group A                     Group B
       --------------             ---------------
       Boys   13-6= 7               Boys   13-12= 1
       Girls  10-9= 1               Girls  10-8= 2
       --------------             ---------------


4. I have assigned the necessary amount of the students in each group:

          Group A                     Group B
       --------------             ---------------
       Boys   6+7= 13              Boys   12+1= 13
       Girls  9+1= 10              Girls  8+2=  10
       --------------             ---------------
        Total     23                Total     23

5. And finally the one that I have left I have added it to the first 
   group:

          Group A                     Group B
       --------------             ---------------
       Boys   13                   Boys   13
       Girls  10+1=11              Girls  10
       --------------             ---------------
        Total     24                Total     23
```

I need to know how to make the assignment to be valid for any number of previously assigned students. I also need to do the same process with three groups (A, B and C).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I bet your problem can be polynomially reduced to the [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or [subsetsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you propose is good one. 
Just please remeber to divide the number of students by the number of groups in `step #2`. That should be enough to make your solution flexible.

Comment: Hello @slawekpl, first of all thanks for replying. Why would I need to divide the number of students by the number of groups? Previously I have the maximum number of students per group, and it can never be the case that there are initially more students than allowed, since this test is done before reaching this step. In this case would be the maximum of 50 students (25 students per group) and as you can see I have 47 in total. If I'm not right tell me, since I'm a bit confused.